# Creating horizontal dataframe from vertical table (with repeated variables)

Tags: r

Need to create usable dataframe using R or Excel

| Variable1 | ID | Variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name of A person 1 | 002157 | NULL |
| Drugs used | NULL | 3.0 |
| Days in hospital | NULL | 2 |
| Name of a surgeon | NULL | JOHN T. |
| Name of A person 2 | 002158 | NULL |
| Drugs used | NULL | 4.0 |
| Days in hospital | NULL | 5 |
| Name of a surgeon | NULL | ADAM S. |

I have a table exported from 1C (accounting software). It contains more than 20 thousand observations. A task is to analyze: How many drugs were used and how many days the patient stayed in the hospital.

For that reason, I need to transform the one dataframe into a second dataframe, which will be suitable for doing analysis (from horizontal to vertical). Basically, I have to create a dataframe consisting of 4 columns: ID, drugs used, Hospital stay, and Name of a surgeon. I am guessing that it requires two functions:

1. for ID it must read the first dataframe and extract filled rows
2. for Name of a surgeon, Drugs used and Days in hospital the function have to check that the row corresponds to one of that variables and extracts date from the third column, adding it to the second dataframe.

Shortly, I have no idea how to do that. Could you guys help me to write functions for R or tips for excel?

Comment: Please focus your question on a single language and show a code attempt in that language. Remove all but one language's tag. Also please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and follow that including showing your input using `dput`.

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I will try posting without mistakes the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for R, I guess you want something like this:

1. load the table, make sure to substitute the `","` with the separator that is used in your file (could be `";"` or `"\t"` for tab etc.).

```r
df = read.table("path/to/file", sep=",")
```

2. create subset tables that contain only one row for the patient

```r
id = subset(df, !is.null(ID))
drugs = subset(df, Variable1 %in% "Drugs used")
days = subset(df, Variable1 %in% "Days in hospital")
#...etc...
```

3. make a new data frame that contains these information

```r
new_df = data.frame(
    id = id$ID,
    drugs = drugs$Variable2,
    days = days$Variable2,
    #...etc...no comma after the last!
)
```

EDIT:
Note that this approach only works if your table is basically perfect! Otherwise there might be shifts in the data.

#=====================================================
EDIT 2:
If you have an imperfect table, you might wanna do something like this:

Step 1.5) , change all NA-values (which in you table is labeled as NULL, but I assume R will change that to NA) to the patient ID. Note that the `is.na()` function in the code below is specifically for that, and will not work with NULL or "NULL" or other stuff:

```r
for(i in seq_along(df$ID)){
  if(is.na(df$ID[i])) df$ID[i] <- df$ID[i-1]
}
```

Then go again to step 2) above (you dont need the id subset though) and then you have to change each data frame a little. As an example for the `drugs` and days data frames:

```r
drugs = drugs[, -1] #removes the first column
colnames(drugs) = c("ID","drugs") #renames the columns

days = days[, -1]
colnames(days) = c("ID", "days")
```

Then instead of doing step 3 as above, use `merge` and choose the ID column to be the merging column.

```r
new_df = merge(drugs, days, by="ID")
```

Repeat this for other subsetted data frames:

```r
new_df = merge(new_df, surgeon, by="ID")
# etc...
```

That is much more robust and even if some patients have a line that others dont have (e.g. days), their respective column in this new data frame will just contain an NA for this patient.

Comment: Thank you very much! 

There is one question bothering me. 

Lets say one patient have one more additional variable, say gender, but the second patient doesn’t have it. So for patient 1 it is Drugs used, Days in hospital, Name of a surgeon and Gender, but for the second patient all the same but the Gender row is missing (it is not null, but missing at all). In this scenario the code will not work properly right?

Comment: this will mess it all up, and one might not even notice. I added a "EDIT 2" that is much more robust